# Evaluating integrals(complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help in evaluating this integral.

$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(3x)}{(x^{2}+1)^{2}}dx
$$
However, I have been able to solve till this point

$$
Re\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{e^{3ix}}{(x^{2}+1)^{2}}dx = \int_{C}\frac{e^{3ix}}{(z^{2}+1)^{2}}+\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{e^{3ix}}{(x^{2}+1)^{2}} = 2\pi iRes
$$
I can't continue. So, I need help completing this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $C$, the upper semicircle?

Comment: @Caffeine the **C** yeah is the upper semicircle.

Comment: @Caffeine, I checked out the link you provided. I understand that solution. In my case, it's different. If you could throw more light, I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: you are right (I didn't notice the second $^2$). I removed the link, my bad.

Comment: The residue at $z  =  i $ is $-ie^{-3}$ so the integral is $(2 \pi i)(-i e^{-3}) = \tfrac{2\pi}{e^3}$. Are you struggling to calculate residues? Please be more explicit in your post.

Comment: @ Brevan Thanks, I will be more explicit next time. It's clear now.